# compile it by suing the root

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

(I would like to apply this algorithm to the attached data by using root package to plot Histograms and I have this error.

```
error Warning: Automatic variable a1 is allocated cuts3.C:31:
Error: Array index out of range v -> [2] valid upto v cuts3.C:31:
Error: Array index out of range v -> [3] valid upto v cuts3.C:31:
Error: Array index out of range v -> [4] valid upto v cuts3.C:31:
Error: Array index out of range v -> [5] valid upto v cuts3.C:31:
Error: Array index out of range v -> [6] valid upto v cuts3.C:31:
```

---

```
     {
     #include <string.h>
       gROOT->Reset();
       ifstream in;
       in.open("calibrated.txt");
       Int_t crysmax=8;
       double e[crysmax]; 
       Int_t nlines = 0;
       Int_t nbins2d=500;
       double coinmin=1, coinmax=1500, minE2d=1, maxE2d=1500, addcoin;

       TFile *f = new TFile("cuts.root","RECREATE");     
       TH2F *hgate2d = new   
       TH2F("Gate2D","",nbins2d,minE2d,maxE2d,nbins2d,minE2d,maxE2d);

       int i=0;
       while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >>e[0]>>e[1]>>e[2]>>e[3]>>e[4]>>e[5]>>e[6]>>e[7];

        addcoin=0.;

    // Background elimination.

    for (int k=0; k<crysmax; k++)
    { 

    double v[k] = log(log(sqrt(e[k]+1)+1)+1);
    for (int p=1; p<=6; p++)
    {
    for (k=p; k<crysmax-p; k++)(
    a1=v[k];
    a2=(v[k-p]+v[k+p])/2;
    double w[k]=min(a1,a2);
    }

    for (k=p; k<crysmax-p;k++)
    {
    v[k]= w[k];
    }

    for (k=0; k<crysmax; k++)
    {
    double b[k]=exp(exp(v[k]-1)-1)* exp(exp(v[k]-1)-1)-1;
    }

     for (int k=0;k<crysmax;k++)
        {
            addcoin=0.;
          if (e[k]>=coinmin&&e[k]<=coinmax) 
          {
            for (int kk=0;kk<crysmax;kk++)
            {
          if (kk!=k) addcoin+=e[kk];
            } 
        hgate2d->Fill(e[k],addcoin);    
          }
         }


        nlines+=1;
        cout << nlines << endl;
    }
        in.close();

       gStyle->SetPalette(1);
       gStyle->SetOptStat(0);
       hgate2d->Draw();                        //  Draw("COL");

         b = new TBrowser();
       f->Write();

    }
```

Comment: Is this all the code? Line 31 of this is `for (k=p; k<crysmax-p; k++)(` which doesn't seem likely. And I suspect the line `TH2F *hgate2d = new  ` won't compile

Comment: @doctorlove the call to `new` continues on the next line

Comment: And `v`is ... ? `double v[k] = ...` looks wrong to me. Shouldn't it be declared / allocated before the loop with sufficient "slots" ? But maybe the code is irritatingly formatted (for my eyes), please advice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in this line:

```
double v[k] = log(log(sqrt(e[k]+1)+1)+1);
```

in the first iteration `k == 0` so you are trying to declare a zero sized array.
I dont understand the code enough to tell you how to fix it, but a zero sized array is definitely not what you want in that place.

Are you using roots interpreter? If yes, I strongly suggest you not to do it. I allows some very obscure stuff and its error messages can be rather confusing. Imho it is always better to compile the code. You will get better error messages and you can be sure that you are not using arcane features of the interpreter that no compiler would allow (for good reasons).